# @MockBean is not applied when running multiple @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot

I've a problem with the MockBean when running multiple test (reducing the success-rate from 100% to ~10%).

The setup is like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class FirstIT{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testGetUser() throws Exception {
    ..

@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class SecondIT{
    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    void testSomethingElse() throws Exception {
    ...
        Mockito.verify(userService, Mockito.timeout(2000).atLeastOnce()).processUserAfterUpload(Mockito.any());
    }
```

When running it stand-alone, it it successful. The debugger shows that the class is a Mockito mock on runtime.

Now when running together (with many more tests), it fails with `Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`. When I debug, I can see that userService is injected as the real object for the SecondIT~testSomethingElse.

I somehow think the context is reused, and MockBean completly ignored if it doesn't run first.

Do I have to annotate every single IT class with `@DirtiesContext`? I mean it's not possible to say reset context before and after this class.

But I'm also not sure that this is intended. That would mean MockBean never works correctly with multiple tests.